# ADO.NET data services Combining Orderby and expand on REST

Tags: c#, javascript, rest, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to get the list from server through javascript using following

```
var request = new Sys.Net.WebRequest();
request.set_httpVerb("GET");
//request.set_orderby("Created");
request.set_url("http://sps2010:39153/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyList?$expand=CreatedBy");
request.get_headers()['Accept'] = 'application/json';
request.add_completed(handleRequestComplete);
request.invoke();
```

Now I want to order above with one of the column, I can order it without using expand, i.e

```
request.set_url("http://sps2010:39153/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyList?$orderby=Created desc");
```

But I can't combine expand and orderby ... strange ... any ideas?

Comment: http://sps2010:39153/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyList?$expand=CreatedBy
-OK
http://sps2010:39153/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyList?$orderby=Created
-OK

http://sps2010:39153/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyList?$expand=CreatedBy$orderby=Created
- NOT OK
I get HTTP 400 "The webpage cannot be found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question.... here is how you combine expand and orderby

```
http://sps2010:39153/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyList?$expand=CreatedBy&$orderby=Created
```

easy really once you know how ... :) hope it will save you guys some time ...